# Else statement not working as expected, and whole script not compatible with IE and Mozilla Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below script is working fine with google chrome. but not responding with IE ans Mozilla browser

JavaScript in below

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function Run() {



  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '001'){
    alert('001');

  }

  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '002'){
   alert('002');
  }

  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '003'){
    alert('003');
  }

    if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == ''){
     alert('Input can not be left blank');
        }

   else {
     alert('INVALID Entry');
     }
}
</script>
```

Form in below

```
<form>
<p>Type code below</p>
<input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext">
<input type="button" value="Go" onClick="Run();">
</form>
```

1. How to get this script work with IE and Mozilla?
2. How to solve Else statement issue, presently if 002 typed in alert showing as 002 and Invalid **(else if worked as you all suggested)**

Whole code in below (which is not working with IE and Moz)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Run() {


 if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '001'){
    alert('001');
  }
  else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '002'){
    alert('002');
  }
  else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '003'){
    alert('003');
  }
  else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == ''){
     alert('Input can not be left blank');
  }
  else {
     alert('INVALID Entry');
  }
}


</script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<form>
<p>Type code below</p>
<input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext">
<input type="button" value="Go" onClick="Run();">
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Seeking for some advice, thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any errors in console ?

Comment: This code works in Firefox: I get an alert. I vote to close.

Comment: [Yup, me too](https://jsfiddle.net/fwnz97q4/1/). Make sure that you're either using a `$(function () { ... });` function to enclose your code, or you've put the calls to the scripts just before the `</body>` tag so that the DOM has a chance to load.

Comment: Works in IE too: https://jsfiddle.net/yffd2p13/ #2 is just that you aren't using `else if`. #1 is not demonstrated by that code.

Comment: **Ask *one* question per question, not two**. Do debugging before asking, with the powerful debugger built into Firefox and IE.

Comment: in IE at bottom showing as "Error on page" once click on Go button, Mozilla no response at all.. kindly advice

Comment: We can't help you with code we cannot see. The above **doesn't cause that problem**, as is evident from the comments and fiddles above. So we can't help, because the problem isn't in the question. (For #1. Again, #2 is just a basic logic error.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated whole code and, hope now you can see all codes, and this code is not working with IE and Moz,

Comment: @trincot  I dont know how its working for you not for me.. give me some advice if possible. do not vote to close this case without giving a solution.

Comment: @Thaju, the best you can do now is provide a fiddle that we can reproduce the problem with in IE or Firefox. If you cannot demonstrate it, and we cannot reproduce it, there is no question.

Comment: @trincot as requested please join fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/krdy7uk6/#&togetherjs=lCprjJjz9E

Comment: @Thaju: [**Yes, it works in IE and Firefox**](http://output.jsbin.com/fototosawe). Literally copied and pasted and updated the jQuery path. Rather than wasting time trying to convince us code doesn't work that does, I strongly recommend **using the debugger to see what's really going on**.

Comment: @Thaju, your fiddle is not configured right: please click on he "JAVASCRIPT *" button and change the "load type" to "no wrap - in `<body>`". Otherwise your function is not defined outside the wrapper that jsfiddle creates for you.

Comment: @Thaju: Your **fiddle** doesn't work because of jsFiddle's brain-dead^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H *surprising* default behavior of wrapping all your code in `window.onload = function() { /*your code here*/};` E.g., the fiddle is not the code in the question. So your `Run` function isn't global, and so you can't use it from an `onxyz`-attribute-style handler (one of the many reasons not to use them). And it doesn't work in Chrome, either, for the same reason.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do not want to waste your or my time, I have uploaded a recoded video in dropbox link, Please see if you willing to help, https://www.dropbox.com/s/j78wofhosxg2zxu/2017-09-09%2C%2019_10_56.avi?dl=0,

Comment: @Thaju: See the comments above, you appear not to have read them.

Comment: To exclude one unknown factor, could you replace `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>`. Does it change anything in IE or Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want all those ifs/elses to be exclusive conditions, right? This is likely what you're looking for:

```
if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '001') {
    alert('001');
}
else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '002') {
    alert('002');
}
else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '003') {
    alert('003');
}
else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == '') {
    alert('Input can not be left blank');
}
else {
     alert('INVALID Entry');
}
```

Comment: Aside: storing `jQuery('#inputtext').val()` in a variable would make for cleaner code...

Comment: For one value you are traversing whole page four times. Really good solution... :D

Comment: @WaldemarIce Our job is to solve the specific problem presented. If you're looking for something else, [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) exists.